# How can I slice the beginning and end of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have 100 values in a dataframe and I want to print a nice table using `tabulate`. This works for me:

```
print(tabulate(dat], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Now, this prints out the entire dataframe. I couldn't get the relevant slicing info here: [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

But I want to print out the first 5 values and then a few `...` and then the last 5 values.

Example:

```
4
2
1
5
1
.
.
4
1
2
4
5
```

How can I do it?

Comment: (Is that closed bracket a typo?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `set_option`, inyour case the max row should be 10, head 5 and tail 5

```
For example 

s=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
pd.set_option('max_rows', 10)
s
Out[1443]: 
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
      ..
7      8
8      9
9     10
10    11
11    12
Length: 12, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If you want to make it temporary, use `with pd.option_context('max_rows', 10): ...`